# Select closest individuals with primary and secondary criteria

Tags: clustering, gower-similarity

I have a set of samples divided in 4 different groups that will be compared by RNA-seq later on. My objective is to select the closest individuals possible, all groups confounded, based on qualitative data.

Some variables should have more weight in this clustering. Here is an example :

```
df=data.frame(
  V1=sample(c(rep("M1",20),rep("M2",20),rep("M3",20))),
  V2=round(runif(n=60, min=0, max=1),0),
  V3=sample(c(rep("M1",20),rep("M2",20),rep("M3",20))),
  V4=round(runif(n=60, min=0, max=1),0),
  V5=round(runif(n=60, min=0, max=1),0),
  V6=round(runif(n=60, min=0, max=1),0),
  V7=round(runif(n=60, min=0, max=1),0),
  Group=sample(c(rep("A",15),rep("B",15),rep("C",15),rep("D",15)))
  )
rownames(df)=paste0(rep("Sample",60),1:60)
```

V1, V4 and V5 are priority criteria to cluster samples. My first idea was to use Gower's distance by weighting variables, then apply hierarchical clustering, separate into 2 branches and keep one branch with the most samples of all groups.

```
library(cluster)
library(dplyr)
library(dendextend)
library(network)

Group=df$Group
Group = as.color(Group)
df=df[,-8]
dim(df)
df[] <- lapply( df, factor)

# calculate distance
d_dist<-daisy(df, metric = "gower", weights =c(10,1,1,10,10,1,1))
# hierarchical clustering

hc<-hclust(d_dist, method = "complete")
dhc <- as.dendrogram(hc)
dhc %>% set("labels", "") %>% plot
colored_bars(colors = Group, dend = dhc)
rect.hclust(hc, k=2, border="red")
```

[image]

My two questions are :

- Would you consider another approach to select the closest individuals based on my primary and secondary criteria ?
- How to chose the weights to apply using Gower's distance ?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Could you elaborate upon your 2nd sentence?  It might be interpreted in different ways.

Comment: You wrote "based on qualitative data" but V4 and V5 are quantitative.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We would like to clusters samples based on all variables, but these variables V1, V4 and V5 should have more importance in the clustering than other variables, so that in priority samples are separated based on those variables and then on the remaining ones. Sorry for the misconception about quantative data, in fact I have qualitative variables which I converted here to a binary format for a clearer example, but maybe I am wrong. I intend to keep them qualitative in my original table.